# MONGODB INSTALLATION in CENTOS

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos7

I am currently walking through the following setup for MongoDB into CENTOS.

Install MongoDB: (latest version is 4.0 right now)
1 Create an /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-enterprise.repo file so that you can install MongoDB enterprise directly using yum:
As root user:

```
a.  cd /etc/yum.repos.d
b.  touch mongodb-enterprise
i.  vim mongodb-enterprise
ii. you will be in the vim editor, click i to insert
iii.    copy and paste the information below

[mongodb-enterprise]
name=MongoDB Enterprise Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.com/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-enterprise/4.0/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

c.  then click the esc button, type :wq and hit enter (wq is write/quit, which will write the information to the file and save it there as you quit out of the editor)
d.  cd /
then…
e.  mkdir data
f.  cd data
g.  mkdir db
h.  mongod (this will show you that mongo is running and looking to connect/listen)
i.  ctrl-c to back out of the mongod

I am getting the following:

bash: mongodb: command not found...

Is there a difference in setting the path when running centos in a Virtual Box VM? I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you follow [Install MongoDB Enterprise Edition on Red Hat or CentOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/)? The current release is 4.4

Comment: Shouldn't the command be `mongod` instead of `mongodb`..? and if you're trying to use the shell, it would be `mongo`